# How can I make sure redundant <p> tags do not break styling?

Tags: jquery, css, tumblr

I am getting an unreliable result from the Tumblr API. When I get a single line of text, I receive just the text. When there are multiple lines, each line is wrapped in a `<p>` tag. So I either get:

```
This is a value with no second line
```

or

```
<p>This is a value</p>
<p>with a second line</p>
```

I want both to appear the same. I have been manually adding the `<p>` around the value, but this will result in:

```
<p><p>This is a value</p>
<p>with a second line</p></p>
```

on multi-line values.

I have a few thoughts on how to fix this, but am unsure which would be the best.

1. Create new CSS style `p p {}` such that offsets the screwed up styling
2. Use jQuery to take DOM contents of redundant `<p>` tags and make them non-redundant
3. Just load the text into a jQuery function, see if there are `<p>` tags, add them if not, then write the result into the DOM.

I'm not sure option 1 will work very well (particularly across browsers), and it seems a bit hacky. Any ideas on if either option 2 or 3 is better, and how I would implement?

Edit: Should've mentioned I'm playing with a Tumblr theme, so Python/PHP/ASP/etc are not available to me (that would make it easier for me!).

Comment: @Zac Just search for a `"<p>"` sequence inside the string. If it's not there, wrap the string in `"<p>"` tags.

Comment: @Michael You would wrap the string in P tags *only* if there is *no* `"<p>"` sequence in the message. If the message is multiline, there will be at least two `"<p>"` sequences in the messege, so you would not wrap the string in P tags....

Comment: @Sime - light has been shown, and I retract my comment. Cheers!

Comment: Don't go for option 1 as you'd have invalid HTML.

Comment: @melhosseiny - I agree. But the HTML be invalid anyway if he's using jquery as a fix. Disable javascript, you still got the same problem ;)

Comment: @tfbox The OP mentioned the Tumblr API, which means that an programming interface is involved here. The message is retrieved using Ajax (most likely). Therefore, without JavaScript, there would be no message...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match it first:

```javascript
result = /^\s*\<p\>.+\<\/p\>$/.test(result) ? result : '<p>' + result + '</p>';
```

Instead of just adding the tags all the time.

Comment: Tried to edit response to escape unescaped slash in regex, but SO won't accept edits of only one char. Regex should read `/^\s*<p>.+<\/p>$/` since neither < nor > require escapement.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just

```
if ( str.indexOf('<p>') === -1 ) {
   str = '<p>' + str + '</p>';    
}
```

So, if there is not a single occurrence of the `"<p>"` string inside your string, this means that the result is "single-line", and you need to wrap it in `"<p>"` tags.

Answer (score 1):

Of your options, I think option 3 is the best way to go. However, I have another idea that might be useful:

Im not sure what platform you are developing on (php/asp.net/etc..) and you could probably do this in the front end as well.

1. receive the message (1 or more lines)
2. use your platforms `split` function to split the string into an array based on a search for the newline character
3. iterate through array values and remove all `<p>`'s if there are any
4. iterate again and prepend and append a `<p> </p>` to each array index
5. truncate each array string into one string, and output to the dom

Viola! Whether its 1 line or 10 lines, no `<p>`'s or 10 `<p>`'s you can rely on the functionality.

This method would "future-proof" this segment of your application, because, as we all have seen, occasionally companies quickly and with out warning change the return result of apis, or alter the way the api works

Answer (score 0):

Assuming PHP; and if the string format is consistent ~

```
$str = 'hello world';
//$str = '<p>a string with a p tag</p>';

if(substr($str,0,3)=='<p>') {

    echo $str;

} else {

    echo '<p> ' . $str . '</p>';

}

// <p>hello world</p>
// <p>a string with a p tag</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution might be to replace all `/<\/p>[^<]*<p>/g` with `<br/>` which would preserve line breaks within multiline paragraphs.